# Vlookup using a dynamic Table_array

Tags: excel

Here is the vlookup we are using:

```
= VLOOKUP('Rates report'!F2,Personnel!$B$2:$H$500,7,FALSE)
```

At this point it is working well. I wish to replace the hard coded value of 500 with a dynamic  value.

I can get the value with

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((Personnel!$A:$A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))))
```

However when I combine the two:

```
= VLOOKUP('Rates report'!F2,Personnel!$B$2:$H$SUMPRODUCT(MAX((Personnel!$A:$A<>"")*(ROW(A:A)))),7,FALSE)
```

I get an error. "The formula you typed contains an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and what is the reason of doing it? This change would make your formula much slower and volatile..alternative: `=VLOOKUP('Rates report'!F2,Personnel!$B:$H,7,FALSE)`. Or better use `INDEX/MATCH` - it's faster: [How to Use INDEX MATCH](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/)

Comment: Each week we add data to the Personnel sheet and I do not want the boss editing the formula. In short I do not know the size of the data on the personnel sheet and do not want to put a really big number there.

Comment: use `Personnel!$B:$H` instead `Personnel!$B$2:$H$500` or better change `VLOOKUP` to `INDEX/MATCH`: [How to Use INDEX MATCH](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/)

Comment: If you want to use your approach, you can create a dynamic reference using `OFFSET()` or `INDIRECT()`.

Comment: @Calvin Those two make the formulae volatile, hence slow...